# RenderScript androidx missmatch type

Tags: android, renderscript

I have created simple instrumented test for android device for playing with renderscript. I have the class for test, a script and a gradle config:

```
import android.renderscript.RenderScript
....

val appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
val renderScript = RenderScript.create(appContext)
assertNotNull(renderScript)
val mScript = ScriptC_test1(renderScript)
```

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.example.renderscript)

const static float3 gMonoMult = {0.299f, 0.587f, 0.114f};
```

```json
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
...
        renderscriptTargetApi 24
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

    }
```

But for following setup I'm getting error that my script in Kotlin cannot accept RenderScript context:

```
e: renderscript/src/androidTest/java/com/example/renderscript/ExampleInstrumentedTest.kt:
 (22, 37): Type mismatch: 
inferred type is android.renderscript.RenderScript! but androidx.renderscript.RenderScript! was expected
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import android.renderscript.RenderScript
```

does not work together with

```
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```